# In iOS 16 local network permission pop-up no longer shows up?

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

My iPhone got updated to iOS recently, iOS 16.0.2

And in this version, the local network permission dialog is no longer shown up, although app is registered the plist entry for network access.

I found this post to be relevant:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711320

Is there any work-around from this issue?

Comment: You already know this is a bug and what the only workaround is, so what do you want with Stack Overflow? File a bug report and hope for the best.

Comment: what workaround?

Comment: You're the one who cited https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711320

Comment: Yes, that post only noted the issue, there was no workaround mentioned in the post. And my post here is asking if anyone met the same issue, and what work around they are using.

Comment: Btw I can repro his/her steps: "Turn off your iPhone, turn it back on again, and launch the existing app, and you will see the local network permissions dialog." but this is not a work around... the permission dialog is not shown at the right trigger point.

Comment: That's why it's called a bug.

Comment: Seeing the same. What I also see (16.2) is uninstalling the app and reinstalling does NOT help, nor resetting the privacy / location settings. When I check in the settings, Local Networks does not show the app. It's like the permission check is never triggered.

Comment: I wish Apple provide a timeline for this, they only have a tracking ID, but when this will be fixed is unknown to external developers.